# Flask app ignores code for a cURL request due to a sys arg param but nothing is passed in sys arg

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest, tox

I have a small flask app that has the code below.
Please note that I have removed a great deal of code to simply my question. If anything needed re-adding or missing, let me know.

```
1   @app.route("/app/data/", methods=['POST'])
2   def methodpost():
3
4       if 'Content-Type' in request.headers and request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
5
6       #some_code
7       #some_more_code
8
9       if not any(['unittest' or 'discover' in arg for arg in sys.argv]):
10
11          #code_calls_external_stuff
12          #more_code
13
14
15      return msg
16
17
18      app.run(host=0.0.0.0, debug=debug, port=5000)
```

When I do a cURL to it using the following:

> curl -X POST "localhost:5000/app/data/" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @jsonBody

It does not go into LINE-11 and LINE-12.

However, when I modify LINE-9 to the following:

```
----FROM:----
if not any(['unittest' or 'discover' in arg for arg in sys.argv]):
----TO:----
if not any(['unittest' in arg for arg in sys.argv]):
```

then it works and calls LINE-11 and LINE-12. The above was only added so I can run UnitTest and Tox while the app is not running because i did not want to make external calls... Is there a way to get around it while keeping the code as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if not any(['unittest' or 'discover' in arg for arg in sys.argv]):
```

isn't doing what you seem to want it to. Simplify this to

```
['x' or 'y' in a for a in ['y']]
```

run it in the REPL, and contemplate why it responds with `['x']`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow sorry, a beginner here but I am not passing any sys.args to it at all?

Comment: sys.args has no effect in that code as written. The precendence of `or` ensures that the answer will always be `['unittest']`, and `not any(['unittest'])` will always be False.

Comment: Right gotcha. I have now split it in to 2 statements and it is a workaround for now...